# Resources for daily/weekly reading

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations

I am a mathematics graduate student looking to transition into theoretical physics. I am teaching myself by reading books and lecture notes, but I would like to have a more up-to-date perspective.

My broad question is then the following: which web resources would you recommend to familiarize myself with theoretical physics research, and more generally with the concepts and ideas of physics that would be new for a mathematician? I am looking for somewhat shorter reading material that I could read on a daily basis, as I have already many good books to read.

The question above might be too broad, so let me be more specific. I am looking for (one or more) blog(s), maintained by a researcher in theoretical physics, that describes her/his research and the techniques she/he uses (or finds interesting). The blog should be updated somewhat frequently.

To give a few examples from mathematics, [Terence Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/)'s blog is an excellent resource both for learning a great deal about the boundaries of many research fields, but also for learning many useful techniques. [Math ∩ Programming](https://jeremykun.com/) and [Eventually Almost Everywhere](https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/) are also excellent resources for news/learning for their respective fields.

I have done my best to check if this reference request had been answered elsewhere. Apologies if it had and I missed it.

Comment: Hi Indigo. This sort of question is off topic on the main site, but would be welcome [in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) (though the room is a little quiet right now). However replies to your question are likely to be disappointing as in general physicists don't seem inclined to blog at the high level. Most physics blogs, even from active researchers, tend to be aimed at a popular audience.

Comment: Typically resource rec's are looking for a book/article/journal/etc on a *single subject* (cf. the [tag:resource-recommendations] tag info), rather than your *anything about (research-level?) physics* request.

Comment: Hi John and Kyle. Thank you for your comments. I'll make sure to drop by the chat to ask my question.

Comment: try this app: https://towardbrightspark.com. It is free and fun.